# Selecting a field from an array of objects using CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, select, lambda, coffeescript

Coming from the C# world, I'm used to doing something like

```
var names = persons.select(x=>x.name);
```

I now want to do a similar thing in CoffeeScript. I have an array of objects and I want to extract a field from each object and put it into an array. I'm sure I can do this using lambdas, I'm just unsure of how the syntax would work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No use of lambdas unless you use the native [Array `map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (equvivalent to C#'s `select`):

```
names = persons.map((x) -> x.name)
```

However, the common CoffeeScript idiom for this is to use a [`for`-loop](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) as an array comprehension:

```
names = (x.name for x in persons)
```

Comment: coffeescript is even better with underscore or lowdash: `names = _(persons).pluck('name')`